# Can I customize select to show the selected value different than what I've selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to show hierarchy in the usual select control. I implemented this by using \u00A0 inside of the option labels.

The hierarchy looks like this:

```
Audi
  - A1
  - A2
  - A3
  - A4
Ford
  - Galaxy
  - Mondeo
  - Focus
```

But when the value selected I need to show the whole value (for ex. "Audi - A4"). And if I expand the select again I still need to see the initial options list with "- A4" selected. Js/angular solution is fine here. 
Please, advice.

Comment: Show us what have you tried this far, in which part are you having issues?

Comment: So I have the select like this - http://jsfiddle.net/alinode/s5zLcbnq/  but I I want to show the whole value for the select itself (selected value) like "Audi - A4" though still having the hierarchy like in jsfiddle.

Comment: So what I want is completely customize the value string of the selected value when the select is not expanded.

Comment: This could get awkward as you will probably need to overlay the `<select>` with another element showing the full text. Before you go down this path, you might want to look at an existing library to help you. I use [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) from the Angular-UI team but others are available.

Comment: Can concatenate text using `ng-options` if you want

Comment: @Rhumborl, yeah, probably this is the only good way for this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get this hierarchy is to use the grouping in ng-options directive, see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/abbhHrAwfkKPcd9xfhm7).

```
$scope.values = [
  { id: 1, make: 'Audi', type: 'A1' }, 
  { id: 2, make: 'Audi', type: 'A2' },
  { id: 3, make: 'Audi',type: 'A3' },
  { id: 4, make: 'Audi', type: 'A4' },
  { id: 5, make: 'Ford', type: 'Galaxy' },
  { id: 6, make: 'Ford', type: 'Mondeo' },
  { id: 7, make: 'Ford', type: 'Focus' }
];
$scope.selectedId = 1;
```

and then

```
<select ng-options="item.id as item.make + ' ' + item.type group by item.make for item in values" ng-model="selectedId"></select>
```

This has the full name of the car in the select, groups by the make, but still, the individual options have the full name of the car.

Comment: The individual options should be just the type (without make) but the selected option should show the full name.

Comment: This would probably call for writing some custom component to use instead of a select. I don't see how the text in the unexpanded select can be different from the text of the individual options.